# jquery simple slideToggle not working as expected

Tags: jquery

This is a simple toggle. The weird thing is that, the event happens when I click anywhere.

This is what my jquery code looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', $('#create_customer'), function(){
    $('#create_customer_form').slideToggle('slow');
    })
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8q0uw80/

Comment: [working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p8q0uw80/1/).

Comment: Pass a selector as the second argument to `on()`, you are passing a jQuery object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector should be something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#create_customer', function(e){
    $('#create_customer_form').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Updated your fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p8q0uw80/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','#create_customer', function(){
$('#create_customer_form').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p8q0uw80/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#create_customer').click(function(){
    $('#create_customer_form').slideToggle('slow');
    });

} );
```

and you can simply do

```
$(document).on('click', '#create_customer', function(){
    $('#create_customer_form').slideToggle('slow');
    })
```